# Check if multiple values are empty separately, and then show an error message

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have an app that allows people to make a post. I am trying to show an alert controller if any of the values are empty. image below

[image]

The user has the option to select up to three photos, pick a category, write a description and then set a price. for instance, if the user selected a photo, forgot to pick a category (which means the UIPicker is == to Job Category) but had a description and price set, How can I present an alert controller telling the user to pick a job category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for each entry, like this:

```
if user didn't select image{
    alert("please select image")
} else if user didn't pick a category{
    alert("please pick a category")
} else if user didn't set a price{
    alert("please set a price")
}
```

If I understood your question well this should solve your problem

Comment: That is the answer thank you! I figured it out now just before you answered. I am having an issue checking the value for the slider and picker but I'm sure ill figure it out.

Comment: @zachwilcox you got this!! feel free to ask and good luck :)

Comment: Thank you! I actually do have a question. I am trying to check if Job category text is equal to Job category. If it is, then the alert should show. Do you know how to see if the textview is equal to a string?

Comment: @zachwilcox if textView.text == "Job Category"

Comment: Hello, Job Category is a picker. Wouldnt i have to access what row it is?? when I click instead of comparing the text?